# Local automation tool for Python

Tags: python, automation

I am looking for good python tool to automate several recurring tasks on localhost (Fabric doesn't fit this requirement since it aims to automate deployment and tasks on remote machines).

E.g. I have to make some preparations (create directories, check access rights and so on) and after that I can run application server which I develop. Or I want to create a script which will create new virtual environment, install several packages (from specific requirements.txt file) and run few commands to produce ready to use env.

Comment: Why can't you just write a bash script for that?

Comment: I can not run bash script under MS Windows ;) I really want to find crossplatform tool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found great tool which fits my need. It is [Paver](http://paver.github.com/paver/)

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use the [Python Standard Library](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html).

Comment: See e.g. Fabric (python deployment tool). It provides nice command line parsing, great loggin, task dependencies and so on. If i will use SPL i will have to implement all these features myself.

Comment: So, use Fabric *and* the standard library!!

Answer (score 1):

Try [SCons](http://www.scons.org/).

Comment: Scons is a *build automation* tool. Also it is a little bit heavy and slow.